# Should event handlers be added dynamically or on document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I use two methods of adding event handlers to dynamically added DOM objects, reason being I don't know which makes more sense.

**Method 1 - with creation**

```
function createButton(){
   var btn = $('<div class = "btn"/>');
   btn.on('click', function(){
     doStuff();
   });
   $('body').append(btn);
}
```

**Method 2 - on document ready**

```
function createButton(){
   var btn = $('<div class = "btn"/>');
   $('body').append(btn);
}

$('document').on('ready', function(){
   $('body').on('click', '.btn', function(){
     doStuff();
   });
});
```

I have long running app considerations as well, and would be concerned about garbage collection issues here.

Comment: Method1. The only reason we wait for document.ready is to be sure the element has been created and added to the body when the script is executed. Which is not a concern if you are adding it yourself.

Comment: Both techniques will work. Method 2 is popular because it makes the code easier to understand, since you can put all the event handlers in one place.

Comment: @Barmar that's good to know, those were my feelings too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Method 1 you're attaching a new, although not unique handler object to each button you create.

In Method 2 you're reusing the same handler object for anything with the .btn class.

In the short term, I'd use Method 2 because you only have 1 handler function for any given button, so you might as well save memory by not creating redundant handlers.

Comment: That is completely right. But Method 1 could be reworded to reuse the handler (basically declaring it outside the createButton function).